# Child div breaks from parent div. why?

Tags: html

I have a parent div and a child div with some text. I want it vertically centered in the parent div. I can't seem to make the child vertically centered in the parent div. and why is it breaking out of the parent div?

I hope the above makes sense. I was trying to upload an illustration but apparently I need 10 reputation to post image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below fiddle: It aligns the text vertically middle of the parent `div`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/43VYg/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px dotted #656565;
  }
 
  .inner {
    padding: 10px;
  }
```

NOTE: This does not support older browsers like IE 7.

You can refer the below link for aligning the text using position absolute/relative

[**Aligning text using absolute positioning**](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/)

Comment: This did the job thanks! But I lost my width 100% on the parent div. I tried position: relative or absolute which gives me my width 100% but my child div is breaking out of the parent again as the original issue.

Comment: Change the `width: 400px` on `.wrapper` to `width: 100%` and that should be all you need.

Comment: @TonyGil : your welcome!!, Do accept it as an answer if it works fine for you.And you can do the changes as mentioned by shshaw , that should work.